# phonegap / cordova windows 8 ajax error?

Tags: ajax, cordova, windows-8

I have a cordova app that makes jqm ajax calls.  It works fine with Android, iOS and WP8.  However, when I build and run for windows 8, the ajax call fails with a 404 error.

I have the latest windows platform version:
phonegap --version
4.2.0-0.23.0

The playtform version is 3.7.1

The Code is this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {
        //handle your data
        navigator.notification.alert('good', null, 'good', 'done');
    },
    error: function (ed) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            JSON.stringify(ed),
            null,
            'Error',
            'Done'

        );
    }
});
```

The getUserDataFail gets called, with the error:
"{\"readyState\":4,\"status\":404,\"statusText\":\"error\"}"

I tried adding the following to the top of my DeviceReady:
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;

I also have the following in my config.xml:

The machine does have internet access and the URL is valid.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, more research resulted in me answering my own question.
The error "app can’t load remote web content in the local context" was being emitted into one of the debugging windows.

In my case, I did not need to really use JSONP.  Changing the call to not specify jsonp resolved the issue:

```
        $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {
        //handle your data
        navigator.notification.alert('good', null, 'good', 'done');
    },
    error: function (ed) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            JSON.stringify(ed),
            null,
            'Error',
            'Done'

        );
    }
});
```

The above works just fine.  I hope this saves someone else hours of searching.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasted 4 hours+ looking for a solution. Your one did the trick!